# Objectives not showing up on the map

Tags: assassins-creed

I've started playing the entire Assassin's Creed saga again, however in AC1 I'm having some problems. In the assassination missions, you need to scale a tower and synchronise viewpoints in order to see your objectives and further your progress in the game. However, I've already scaled all of the towers and synchronized all of the viewpoints, so it's impossible for me to see any of the objectives! This has happened in all of the poor districts, so I can't see any objectives on the map, only "help civilians".

Is there any way to solve this? Or do I just need to start the story again?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a common error in assassins creed. Your best choice would be to do the side missions that appear on the map because sometimes the system actually forgets the fact that you've done the side missions to activate the assassination target mission. So you need to just run through a couple of side missions. If that doesn't work it could possibly be corrupted data.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to filter your map to show/hide Places of Interest, Quests, that sort of thing.  Have you turned off your Quest indicators?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe also see if you need to zoom your map out a little bit?    If you have heaps of icons up they could be overlapping.